# udisksctl mount a different subvolume of an already mounted btrfs partition

Tags: mount, btrfs, udisks

I have a btrfs partition with several subvolumes, one of which is /. I have another subvolume with some other stuff that I also want to mount, but trying to mount it with udisksctl:

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/mapper/container -o subvol=other
```

gives me this error:

```
Error mounting /dev/dm-0: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.AlreadyMounted: Device /dev/dm-0 is already mounted at `/'.
```

It mounts fine with `mount /dev/mapper/container -o subvol=other /mnt`. Is there anything I can do to get this to work with udisksctl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read the man page (`man udisksctl`)! It says you should use `--options`.

If this is not working, then `subvol` is considered an unsafe option (IMHO, it should). If so, you can use the `mount` command or you can set the options directly in `/etc/fstab` for a given mount point.

Comment: I did read the man page, and I am using `--options` (as `-o`).  I did a quick test, and it appears that both subvol and subvolid are not allowed options, although it gives a different error message.